# How do I list all images in a folder using C#?

Tags: c#

I need to list all of the images in a folder using C#.

I searched Stack Overflow and found some threads talking about it, but the questions were covering PHP. I need to do this with C#.

Comment: What have you tried? In fact, I dare say you probably havent even Google Searched this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\YourImgDir");

FileInfo[] Images = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

You can substitute whatever image file extensions you so desire.

Answer (score 5):

This is for C#:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Location of Files", "*.jpg"); //.png, bmp, etc.
```

Comment: When you say images.. do you actually mean Files or do you actually mean .jpg, bpm, gif, ect....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles` to get the filenames of files in a directory:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("directory_path", "*.jpg");
```

You can change `.jpg` for any other file type. The asterisk is a wildcard character.